# How to ORDER all columns FIRST in mysql tableTHEN limit

Tags: mysql

Take an example of a table (`tblabc`) with the following data

```
id  amount
1   10
2   20
3   50
4   30
5   90
6   80
7   70
8   40
9   100
10  60
```

Normally, if you apply the code `` SELECT * FROM tblabc ORDER BY `amount` DESC LIMIT 0,2 `` it will return its result based on the first 2 columns only, which is not my desired result

**What it will return**

```
id  amount
1   20
2   10
```

You can clearly see that the result is only from the first 2 columns instead of the whole table, sorted.

**My desired result would be:**

```
id  amount
9   100
5   90
```

Also how the method applied should be consistent with the pagination i.e at the second phase `` SELECT * FROM tblabc ORDER BY `amount` DESC LIMIT 2,2 `` it should produce

```
id  amount
6   80
7   70
```

Comment: Your query does what you want. Did you try and run it?

Comment: @GBM - The queries are missing the `ORDER` keyword. I strongly suspect a discrepancy between what's real and what's being described.

Comment: @MatBailie I have edited it

Comment: Something is still different from reality. Because, as described, those queries DO give the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired results are wrong.

But you need only to order it by amount DESC

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `amount` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`id`, `amount`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '10'),
>   ('2', '20'),
>   ('3', '50'),
>   ('4', '30'),
>   ('5', '90'),
>   ('6', '80'),
>   ('7', '70'),
>   ('8', '40'),
>   ('9', '100'),
>   ('10', '60');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY `amount` DESC LIMIT 0,2
> ```
>
> ```
> id | amount
> -: | -----:
>  9 |    100
>  5 |     90
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY `amount` DESC LIMIT 2,2
> ```
>
> ```
> id | amount
> -: | -----:
>  6 |     80
>  7 |     70
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bc8e6403dd6b9982b0bb9150d0e8085d)*

Comment: Why do you have `, id ASC` in the `ORDER BY`? And why are you inserting string in to integer columns?

Comment: Ah yes true, I had a slight error in my pagination, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The query should be “select * from tableabc ORDER BY amount” not just BY. That wouldnt even work in MySQL.